# How to convert a PDFBox PDPageContentStream to a byteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to understand how to use PDFBox in a web application.
PDFBox examples everywhere says to use the file system to save the file first.
Here is an example from web....
try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {

```
        PDPage myPage = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(myPage);

        try (PDPageContentStream cont = new PDPageContentStream(doc, myPage)) {

            cont.beginText();
            .....
            cont.endText();
        }

        doc.save("src/main/resources/wwii.pdf");
```

}

But how can I do that in a webapplication (deployed in WebLogic) in a production environment????
Because after the application is deployed, I cannot say to write to a file system because we do not know what type of a file system it is used.
The only way out is to know how to convert the cont object to a byte array and store it in the memory before displaying..

I tried significant amount of time to find out how to coinvert the cont object in the above example to a byte array input stream to I could use it in the next step - which is displaying it in a webpage.

Comment: why would you save the page content stream? It's the PDDocument you should save. You can write to a ByteArrayOutputStream object.

Comment: When the application deployed in the server, how can I save it in a file system? I cannot say C:\... or D:\.... ect because I do not know multiple clients what OS they use. So either I have to save the file in the server somewhere or have the final PDF document as a stream before shippping it into a Browser. But the PDFBox do not give a method to convert the document to a byteStream.

Comment: I am following the example in https://zetcode.com/java/pdfbox/ and trying to implement the same in a WebLogic Java application

Comment: *"But the PDFBox do not give a method to convert the document to a byteStream."* - PDFBox allows you to save to an `OutputStream`. Simply use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` (as @Tilman has proposed), take its `byte[]`, and wrap it in a `ByteInputStream`. Alternatively, if you don't want the whole generated PDF in memory, use a pair of `PipedOutputStream` and `PipedInputStream`. Java 101.